# How do I convert three digit hexadecimal String to Color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, hex

I want to convert "#0ff" this hexadecimal string into Color

I have searched it But I only found answers with the hexadecimal string with length 6 digits

If I do like this `Color(0xFF0ff)` It displays nothing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Web defines colours in three ways: explicit colour name, 3 hex digits, or 6 hex digits. So `#0ff` is a colour, and most programs (and for sure web) understand it. But a #abc is equivalent to #aabbcc. Just write twice every digit (as character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web defines colours in three ways: explicit colour name, 3 hex digits, or 6 hex digits.

If you have 3 digits, you should "double" every digit (as character, not as value), so #abc is to be read as #aabbcc. Why? It is short, and it helped to select fewer colours (in the olden time we have 8 or 16bit colours), and screens may not be so accurate.

Do your `#0ff` should be read as `#00ffff`.

Note: These 3 digit colours are now considered **obsolote**, see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#simple-colour, but still used on many places (e.g. #fff for white).

Comment: Wouldn't #fff be white, not black?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz: right, corrected. Thanks

Comment: whatwg.org is NOT the standard for colors on the web, and your claim that 3 digit hex is obsolete is false. Here is the actual standard: w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#numerical   ...  whatwg.org you linked is the standard for basic HTML, and "simple" colors, but that is not the standard for color on the web. A different WHATWG document points there: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#parsed-as-a-css-color-value

Comment: @Myndex: "considered obsolete". For sure it will not disappear in next 10 years, and obviously standard needs to explain also the 3 digits. It is not recommended to use, "obsolete" doesn't mean not to be used. If Whatwg is not the reference for web, what do you consider reference? w3c? but usually they are aligned (maybe with some delay)

Comment: You are not looking at the correct standard for color. I responded in depth in my answer to the OP. You are referencing the HTML, and HTML is not where colors belong in the first place, they belong in CSS, and I assure you that #rgb is not obsolete nor depreciated, and is in the standard released just last month. W3 is part of WHATWG, but HTML is the wrong standard to reference for this context. CSS 3 is the current canonical standard, and yes it is at the W3 as I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The "accepted" answer by GC is incorrect in so many ways, in fact the *only thing* he got right is that #0ff = #00ffff.

First, the current ***standard*** for color for CSS and web content is here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#numerical

### `#0ff` is a perfectly legal and not obsolete color definition.

The permissible forms for defining sRGB color for the web are:

```css
* { color: #f00; }                /* #rgb */
* { color: #ff0000; }             /* #rrggbb */
* { color: rgb(255,0,0); }        /* each value is 0-255 */
* { color: rgb(100%, 0%, 0%); }   /* each value is 0%-100% */
* { color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%); }   /* red using hsl "hue sat lightness" */
* { color: "red"; }               /* color keyword */
```

*Not shown above: transparency or alpha syntax.*

#### String Theory

For the first two in the list, the color value is parsed as a STRING data type and not a numeric value.

> *If I do like this Color(0xFF0ff) It displays nothing*

When you `Color(0xFF0ff)` it was invalid and ignored. `0x123456` is a numeric value in hex, which equals the integer value `1193046` to write it as a *string* that is valid for a CSS-type of color definition, you need to write it as `#123456`

#### Three's Company, Six is the Clone. Or Sith. Or Something...

In the "three digit" format, each hex value is duplicated (cloned LOL), so #abc becomes #aabbcc.

For a math definition, `0xCC = 0xC * 0x10 + 0xC` so if we have the hex numeric 0xABC:

```
0xAABBCC = 0xA * 0x110000 + 0xB * 0x1100 + 0xC * 0x11
```

So, if you are working with numeric data types, then use`x = 0x123456`, but if you are sending strings to some other API, then `x = '#123456'`  ... And also remember that if you need to accept `'#123456'`, that it's going to be a string unless you convert it to a numeric, easy in JS with `parseInt(x,base);` where the base of course is 16.

##### Side note to comment on a different answer:

GC said:

> *Why? It is short, and it helped to select fewer colours (in the olden time we have 8 or 16bit colours), and screens may not be so accurate.*

None of this is relevant. #rgb and #rrggbb have been in the CSS standard since the very beginning in the mid 90s, and #rgb has *ALWAYS* expanded to #rrggbb, regardless of system capability, and in the mid 90s 8bit per channel (aka 24bit color) was the norm as it still is today.

Moreover, color is a part of design and presentation, and *design* should be *abstracted to CSS*, and not in the HTML which is for content structure.

The fact that the HTML spec wants to "simplify" color declarations has more to do with efficiency in parsing the DOM, and nothing you mentioned. Colors should not be in HTML at all, they should in the CSS, and I assure you #rgb is not "obsolete" it is very much a part of the latest CSS color standard approved a month ago, linked at the beginning of this post.

**The "actual why" is three digit color is *easier to use***

`#fea` is a lot easier to remember than `#fcecb0` and yet they are nearly identical in appearance.

The full #rrggbb is useful when you need to exactly match an 8 bit sRGB color such as in an image. Otherwise, **there is no issue with using #rgb instead of #rrggbb**, and there are plenty of reasons to do so, none of which have anything to do with bit depth, nor for that matter "screen accuracy" which is still up to user adjustment and calibration now as it was then.